# Windows 2012 R2 Essentials and the Client Restore Service

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, bare-metal

I have installed the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit for Windows 10 onto my Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials system in order to be able to do a full system restore of my Windows 10 Workstations.

Unfortunately, when I click Start on the Client Restore Service I get a message telling me that the Windows PE environment cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be a bug. I have just uninstalled Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit for Windows 10 and successfully installed the 8.1 version